# php seo 404 error in webmaster tool

Tags: php, seo, search-engine, google-search-console

I have a  PHP site wich contains 1000s of pages ...
Every day i delete 10s of pages which already indexed by GOOGLE....

When visitor come to one of thos pages i do check to see if it is deleted or not ...
If deleted i redirect the user to the search page to start search for similar contents ...
I am using this code :

```
if($deleted = true){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: /products-search.php");
    exit(); 
}
```

the problem that in GOOGLE webmaster tool i get alot of soft 404 errors for the pages of this type.
the message say  : The target URL doesn't exist, but your server is not returning a 404 (file not found) error. Learn more

i dont want the user to get 404 error  .... i need him to go to search page ...

How to solve this ?

Comment: You really don't want to use a 301. Browsers cache 301s indefinitely (as they're "permanent") so if you wind up putting that content back or reusing its URL some of your users won't be able to get to it. It's also confusing for search engines, as it *should* be a 404. Why not have your 404 page show a "Did you mean to go here?" sort of thing?

Comment: `header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");` does your comparison work? `if($deleted=true)` ?? or is this a typo error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still return a 404 unless you expect to put that page back up later.  A redirect is a bad idea for SEO in this case.

What you could do is return a 404 in the header but show the search page anyway:

```
<?php

header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");

echo "The page you're looking for doesn't exist or was deleted. You can use the search below to find more...";

// include search box here
```

Comment: would you please provide code example for my case ?

Comment: I updated my answer to show it as code.  It's as simple as it gets.

Comment: No need for location  line (    header("Location: /products-search.php");) ?

Comment: No, you just need to organize your code so that you can include "products-search.php" from there.

Comment: could make products-search the 404 page https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-404-page-in-apache